# Помогите с регулярным выражением мобильного телефона

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Нужно поставить проверку,чтобы был введён только мобильный телефон.
Как я примерно представил,их 2 типа,7и значный и 10 значный.И все они начинаются с 9.
Составил регулярку,но она не работает,помогите,где я не так что понял?

> /(9[0-9]{6,6})|(9[0-9]{9,9})/

Я поставил 2 возможных варианта,что они начинаются с 9 и только числовой вариант,возможно 6 чисел после 9 или 9 чисел после 9...Но это выражние делает совершенно не то что я ожидаю...То есть есть 10 числовая последовательность,но регулярка видет в ней только первый вариант,обрезая телефон
заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде всего, поменяйте местами группы, иначе до второй группы проверка никогда не дойдёт:

```
(9[0-9]{9,9})|(9[0-9]{6,6})
```

Далее, вышеприведённое выражение можно упростить до следующего эквивалентного:

```
9\d{6}(\d{3})?
```

[Демонстрация в действии.](http://regexr.com?36n75)

Comment: 911230233 в таком номере он тоже находит соответствие,хотя не должен

Comment: просто он начинает реагировать на номера с 7 и выше,а мне надо чтобы только на 7 или на 10

Comment: Не уверен, что верно вас понял. Обновил ссылку на пример, посмотрите, то ли это, что вам нужно?

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам нужно просто поменять их местами.
    /^(9[0-9]{9})|(9[0-9]{6})$/

Comment: не совсем,мне главное чтобы он реагировал на числовые последовательности начинаюшиеся строго с 9 и имеющие продолжительность либо 7(вместе с 9ой),либо 10(вместе с 9ой)